# conditional not exits into join

Tags: sql, join

Not sure I'm stuck with an 'instant stupid', or  if this query is really a tricky one.

So I have two tables.

```
table A (aid,b,c) - aid unique
table B (aid, country) - aid not unique
                        (eg: (aid-country) = 2-ITALY, 2-JAPAN etc.)
```

I'm trying to write using a join to find **all aids in A that's not there in B , or any aids in A that's in B but not the aid has no matching country ITALY**

A simple subquery would be either:

```
select * from A where aid is not in (select aid from B where country = 'ITALY')

select * from A where not exists (select aid from B where country = 'ITALY')
```

In example above, if table **A** has `aid=1,2,3,4`  and table **B** has only two records `(2-ITALY, 2-JAPAN)`, I should only get `1,3,4` as the result. But If the two records were `(2-USA, 2-JAPAN)`, the result would be `1,2,3,4`.

The following left joins won't work.

```
select * 
from A left join B on A.aid=B.aid 
where b.country<>ITALY AND B.aid is null

select * 
from A left join B on A.aid=B.aid 
where ( B.aid is null) .
    OR (where A.aid=B.aid and b.country<>ITALY)
```

as this will still see `2-JAPAN` as matching if the records in B were  `(2-ITALY , 2-JAPAN)`.

What would be the equivalent join if I were to replace the subquery?

Comment: Your question is pretty good for the community, good job (well, it's also quite simple, but it doesn't matter). Next time you're facing with a SQL problem, please provide a sqlfiddle to help the readers test your datasets and actually compare their result with the desired one. reference: www.sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error was in using `<> 'ITALY'` instead of `= 'ITALY'`. Understandable mistake because you're looking to exclude records if ITALY exists, but a double negative makes a positive, and you already have your negative in `where B.aid is null`, so what you really want is to find rows where the value *is* ITALY, and then *exclude* those matches from the results.

```
select A.aid from A
left join B on A.aid = B.aid and b.country = 'ITALY'
where b.aid is null
```

Comment: That's exactly what was going on. (I think I had initially tried with an '=' and FELT it didn't work.)

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a try. It will match on country = ITALY and then return only those rows that do not match (e.g., country is null). If you need distinct values of aid, you can obviously just add a distinct to the select statement and the relevant columns.

```
select * 
from 
    a
    left join b
        on  a.aid = b.aid
            and b.country = 'ITALY'
where
    b.country is null
```